# How to apply a WHERE condition with count(distinct) and group by in a query?

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) AS Counter,COL1 FROM TABLE_NAME IG group by COL1
```

It counts the distinct values present in a column.
So, if the table is like

```
COL1

AA
AA
AA
BB
BB
CC
```

The result will be - , based on the above query

```
Counter   COL1
3         AA
2         BB
1         CC
```

I want to see all those records for which the counter has value greater than 1, i.e The result must be like suggested below

```
Counter   COL1
    3         AA
    2         BB
```

How to apply this `WHERE` condition on the above query?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) ... GROUP BY COL1` would be a series of rows with a count of `1` for all distinct values in `COL1`. And because of this your query will return 0 rows, even after adding the appropriate `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: thanks for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is a different query, with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter
    , COL1
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for HAVING

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) AS Counter,COL1 
FROM TABLE_NAME IG 
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) > 1
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.